# Doesn't populate the modal view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

So basically, I want to populate the twitter bootstrap with the Ruby on Rails looping over the hash of records:

```
var popup = '<div id='+ key +' class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">' + 
    '<div class="modal-body">'+  
        <% v.each_with_index do |s, i| %>
            <%= i %>
        <% end %> 

    '</div>' + 
'<div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button></div>' + '</div>'
```

$(popup).appendTo("body");

However it gives me only the first element... 0

PS the date is 100% in the hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to

```
var popup = '<div id='+ key +' class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">' + '<div class="modal-body">'
<% v.each_with_index do |s, i| %>
  popup = popup + <%= i %>
<% end %>
popup = popup + '</div>' + '<div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button></div>' + '</div>'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missed (probably mistyped) :

```
<%= v.each_with_index do |s, i| %>
```

if you'd like to run Ruby statement in your `.erb` template.

Comment: What is the result of this: `v.each {|n| puts n}` on the Rails console?

Comment: It gives me a list of records. More over I'm trying to `alert(popup)`: 

`<div id=2013060308 class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"><div class="modal-body"><li> 0 </li><li> 1 </li><li> 2 </li><li> 3 </li><li> 4 </li></div><div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button></div></div>`